# Twisted Agent won't build request from bytes

Tags: python, twisted

I'm learning Twisted by trying to build an RSS agregator. When I try to build requests using the web agent, I'm told that I did not provide the url argument as bytes :

```
[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.web._newclient.RequestGenerationFailed'>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found>]
```

But I think I did :

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.client import Agent

def request_sent(response):
    print ('I got something!')

def request_failed(reason):
    print (reason)

def feed_loader_main():
    """
    Starts and manage the reactor
    """
    agent = Agent(reactor)

    d = agent.request(
        'GET',
        'http://www.example.com'.encode('utf8')   ##### <- HERE
    )

    d.addCallback(request_sent)
    d.addErrback(request_failed)

    print ('Firing reactor!')
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    feed_loader_main()
```

Is it Twisted black magic going on here or just poor encoding from me?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include both Twisted and Python version numbers? There use to be a problem with `Agent` and Python 3 but I believe it was solved a while ago. Nevertheless try prefixing your strings with `b` (if you're using Python 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception didn't actually say that you didn't provide the URL as bytes.  It just said somewhere it wanted bytes and got str (unicode) instead.

I'm guessing you're on Python 3 since I can replicate your exception with your code on Python 3 and not on Python 2.  I'm not sure what version of Twisted you're using but I suspect this isn't terribly Twisted-version-specific.  Nevertheless, it's a good idea to specify the versions of Python and Twisted in future questions.

The other value you're passing in to `request` is `"GET"` and on Python 3, that's a str (unicode).  If you encode that (or just make it a bytes literal with `b"..."`) then the exception goes away.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I'm using Python 3.5 and Twisted 17.0. It somehow made sense to me that the reactor would process URL's as bytes in order to build the request, but I didn't know there was an encoding constraint on contextual parameters such as GET (that's why I didn't even think the error could come from there). It's kind of weird.

Comment: It seems to me like it would be better if there were symbolic constants for the different HTTP methods, eg `GET` instead of `b"GET"`, etc.  That's slightly more constraining in case someone wants to issue a funky verb (which is technically possible though probably very rare).  However, porting to Python 3 has consumed the vast majority of the Twisted development effort for many years so improvements like this have mostly fallen by the wayside.

Comment: It makes sense. If I ever have the time, I'll try to make a pull request. That's a good opportunity to contribute to the codebase.